# How does Hard Voting select a result with an even number of classifiers in a VotingClassifier in scikit-learn?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I have two classifiers in a Voting Classifier which are both being used to predict whether an instance is class 0 or class 1. The results are aggregated using hard voting (which uses a majority vote), however I am unsure how the VotingClassifier makes the decision with an even number of classifiers.

Answer (score 2):

Its mentioned in the [documentation here](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/ensemble.html#majority-class-labels-majority-hard-voting)

> In the cases of a tie, the VotingClassifier will select the class
>   based on the ascending sort order. E.g., in the following scenario
>
> ```
> classifier 1 -> class 2
> classifier 2 -> class 1
> ```
>
> the class label 1 will be assigned to the sample.

So as explained here, in case of a tie, the alphabetical order will be used to give out the result.

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution is to use confidence value to break the tie.